# Why does tilde V output ~V [LogLevel ERROR]?

Tags: ssh, password, git

One of the password variations I use a github account contained the characters `~V`. When prompted for the password to push to Github, I typed in `~V` and it output

```
~V [LogLevel ERROR]
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're on an SSH session. SSH lets you send special commands to SSH itself (not the shell you logged into) using certain "escape" sequences. From [`man ssh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ssh.1):

```
ESCAPE CHARACTERS
 When a pseudo-terminal has been requested, ssh supports a number of
 functions through the use of an escape character.

 A single tilde character can be sent as ~~ or by following the tilde by a
 character other than those described below.  The escape character must
 always follow a newline to be interpreted as special.  The escape
 character can be changed in configuration files using the EscapeChar
 configuration directive or on the command line by the -e option.

 The supported escapes (assuming the default ‘~’) are:
 ...

 ~V      Decrease the verbosity (LogLevel) when errors are being written
         to stderr.

 ~v      Increase the verbosity (LogLevel) when errors are being written
         to stderr.
```

So, if you pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> for the username prompt, then `~V` as the first two characters of the password, SSH would interpret that as a command to increase the log verbosity.

So, over SSH, to enter `~V` as the first two characters of a password, either:

1. Press `~` twice so that it gets treated as a literal `~` (per the second paragraph in the quote above): `~~V`, or
2. Do something at the start of the prompt to break the sequence (type a character and delete it, for example).